# 2010: Allow editing documents without editing web part pages

Tags: 2010, permissions

In SharePoint 2010, what is the best way to allow users with the "Edit Items" permissions to edit documents, but not web part pages?

SP2010 lists this permission set as "Edit items in lists, edit documents in document libraries, and customize Web Part Pages in document libraries."

My current thought is to make sure all web part pages are in a document library, and customize the permissions of that document library with different permissions.  The problem is, now I have additional document libraries with unique permissions, which increases maintainability.

I'd like to get to what 2007 had, where Contribute permissions did not allow users to edit web part pages.

What's the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the best way is to place web part pages in their own library (SitePages?) and break inheritance on that, removing the contribute permissions.